# Android -> onActivityResult-> processing of image -> null pointer exception on some devices

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, photo

i was noticed, that my app is crashing on some device in **onActivityResult** method.

I tried to solve that but without luck, does not anybody idea, what can cause this problem? In following method i got always IO exception on some devices (for example HUAWEI ASCEND P6).

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            Log.i(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "Trying to process image");
            GlobalApplication globalAppClass = ((GlobalApplication) getApplicationContext());
            AppHelper helper = new AppHelper();
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            Bitmap resizedBitmap;
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "DAMAGE_" + globalAppClass.getEanCode() + "_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
            String dirname =  "smartt/"+globalAppClass.getEanCode();

            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
            resizedBitmap = helper.getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 768, 1024);
            helper.createDirectoryAndSaveImage(resizedBitmap, imageFileName, dirname);
            // place thumbnail into image view
            //mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

            TextView photoCountTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.damageReportTakenPhotosCountTv);
            photoCountTv.setText(R.string.foto_attached);
            photoCountTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

            TextView dataPassingTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.damageReportPassingTitle);
            dataPassingTv.setText(R.string.data_passing);
            dataPassingTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "onActivityResult method cannot be processed, file not found", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "onActivityResult method cannot be processed, IOE Exception", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "onActivityResult method cannot be processed, IOE Exception", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: Crash log:
01-26 18:49:31.580: I/SMARTT(4500): Trying to process image
01-26 18:49:31.587: E/SMARTT(4500): onActivityResult method cannot be processed, IOE Exception
01-26 18:49:31.587: E/SMARTT(4500): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 18:49:31.587: E/SMARTT(4500):  at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:447)
01-26 18:49:31.587: E/SMARTT(4500):  at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.getBitmap(MediaStore.java:804)
01-26 18:49:31.587: E/SMARTT(4500):  at com.kwe.smartt.DamageReportActivity.onActivityResult(DamageReportActivity.java:153)

Comment: I think, after returning to your activity, the imageUri is getting null, you have to declare the imageUri before calling the startActivityForResult().

Comment: Could You please provide some example? I don't know how did you exactly think.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check if all your resources are in place. Remember, that IDEs often create alternative directories for differing screen sizes (e.g. *drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi*, etc.). Check, what kind of screen is used in case of the failing configuration.

You can also take a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html